# Read Timed Out on FTP upload

Tags: ftp

Every time i try to upload a website with any ftp client i get Read Timed Out error. The file is copied on the server but it's 0kb size. I searched everywehre on the net, and tried several things; passive mode, disabling the firewall, making a trace route test to see if the firewall blocks any port... but i'm getting the same error Read Timed Out.

I've chatted with the technical support yesterday and the technician told me that there's a saturation of 98% on my channel (i don't even know what does that mean but i was happy to know that), and ask me to call next day because he can not manage this issue directly. I called them today two times, and they did the same test and they don't see any problem!! 
This error is driving me crazy now five days, please help if you have experimented that or if you have any suggestion!

(yes one more thing; this happens on Mac OsX(SL), on windows everything is ok. Even after i've installed the OsX, i'm getting the same thing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the problem came form my internet connexion. My internet provider had reset my connexion and now everything is ok.